# Table rows jquery throw the error message too much recursion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting the error message too much recursion. Why?

The [following code is](http://jsfiddle.net/AzZw4/43/) supposed to expand/collapse the table rows upon clicking on the image. If the image does not exist the there would be a div upon clicking on which the last rows will expand/collapse

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide(); 
    //$(".lvlcollapse .level4").hide();
    $("tr.lvlcollapse").click(function() {
        //alert($(this).find("img").attr("src"));
        if ($(this).find("img").attr("src") != undefined) {
            var tnow = $.now();
            var allClass = $(this).attr('class');
            var level = getLevel($(this));
            var state = getClass($(this), '^clicked\\d+$');
            if (state == undefined) {
                state = "closing";
                $(this).addClass("clicked" + tnow);
            }
            else {
                $(this).removeClass(state);
                tnow = state.substr(6);
            }
            switchImage($(this));
            $(this).nextAll(".lvlcollapse").each(function() {
                var sublvl = getLevel($(this));
                var subtnow = 0;
                var substate = getClass($(this), '^closed\\d+$');
                if (substate != undefined) subtnow = substate.substr(5);
                if (sublvl > level) {
                    if (state == "closing" && subtnow == 0) {
                        $(this).addClass("closed" + tnow);
                        $(this).toggle();
                    }
                    else if (subtnow == tnow) {
                        $(this).removeClass(substate);
                        $(this).toggle();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            });

        } else {
            //alert('No Image ');
            $(".button").click(function(event) {
                //var $this2 = $(this);
                var allLevel4 = $(this).next(".lvlcollapse.level4");
                $($(this)).toggle('fast', function() {
                    if (allLevel4.is(":visible")) {
                        $(this).html("Show Attempts");
                        alert('hello2');
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        $(this).html("Hide Attempts");
                        alert('hello3');
                        return false;
                    }

                }) event.preventDefault();
            }).trigger("click");
        }
    });
    $(".lvlcollapse.level2").filter(function() {
        return $(this).next(".lvlcollapse.level3").is(":visible");
    }).trigger("click");
    //$(".button").filter(function() { return $(this).next(".lvlcollapse.level4").is(":visible"); }).hide();
});​
```

Comment: You should create a http://jsfiddle.net/ for us to see the problem and understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: There's no longer a "too much recursion" message, see comments under my answer, this should be closed and a new question should be asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that looks funny is that you're adding a click handler to the button within the click handler for `tr.lvlcollapse`. That will create a new handler everytime you click on it and it will trigger all the previous handlers when you call `trigger.click()`

Since the click event bubbles, it will also trigger the click handler for all the parents. If the button is inside `tr.lvlcollapse`, that could be your problem.

Two things you need to do:

- Don't set handlers from within handlers unless you really know what you are doing and you have a plan to unbind the handlers, or at the very least, remove existing binding before binding. Note that this is less common, you typically do not add handlers from within handlers.
- Call `event.stopPropagation()` if you don't want ancestor nodes to handle the click

Comment: How would i  unbind tr.lvlcollapse click event

Comment: `$("tr.lvlcollapse").off('click')` But that will remove all handlers, it'd be safer to set your events using namespaced events so you aren't removing all handlers. And I'm not sure that is the right thing to do, without an example to look at, it's almost impossible to suggest something more directly http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events

Comment: well Removed the button click ouside and it works partially. But instead of hiding the next row with class level4 it hides the button itself$(".button").click(function(event) {
      //var $this2 = $(this);
      var allLevel4 = $(this).next(".lvlcollapse.level4");
      $($(this)).toggle('fast', function(){
       if (allLevel4.is(":visible")){
        $(".button").html("Show Attempts");

        return false;
       }else{
        $(".button").html("Hide Attempts");

        return false;
       }

      })
event.stopPropagation();
     });

Comment: @user1880192 You expect me to read the code in the comments? If you have updated code, you should update the question and format it properly. Best thing is to create a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @user1880192 I clicked on the images  `Test User Path – 1 Activity 1 Bundle` and got no error

Comment: if you look at the code click on the Test Activity – 1E Quiz Scored  see attempts you still get 1 record displayed I do not understand why

Comment: @user1880192 Dude, you are not making sense, your question says that your problem is "I am getting the error message too much recursion. Why?" But in your jsfiddle there is no "too much recursion" message

Comment: Then this question should be closed. You are not supposed to ask two different questions in one post. Sorry about that, but that's how the site stays useful, one question per post

Answer (score 0):

What happens with those alerts you got commented out?  Are you seeing them repeat over and over if you uncomment them?  That $('.button').click() in the else looks bad.  You only need to register it once, but you have it in the click listener so it will be registered every time the user clicks a link. Pull that out and register on document ready or when the table is built.  Not in response to the user clicking something.

Comment: my table looks like this<table border="1">
<tr class="lvlcollapse level1"><td>1</td></tr>
<tr class="lvlcollapse level2"><td>2</td></tr>
<tr><td><div class="button">click Here</div></td></tr>
<tr class="lvlcollapse level4"><td>4</td></tr>
<tr class="lvlcollapse level1"><td>1</td></tr>
<tr class="lvlcollapse level2"><td>2</td></tr>
<tr><td><div class="button">click Here</div></td></tr>
<tr class="lvlcollapse level4"><td>4</td></tr>

</table>